# what does mean numbers in paranthesis of multi layer perceptron like (64,128,1024)

Tags: deep-learning, point-clouds, mlp

Hello every one i'm reading pointnet papper but i cant understand the numbers of network architecture can you explain this to me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/futuI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It means 3 fully connected layers, having neurons in each layer as 64, 128 and 1024 respectively. Between each layer, there is [batch normalization](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/batch-normalization-in-3-levels-of-understanding-14c2da90a338) as well as [RELU](https://machinelearningmastery.com/rectified-linear-activation-function-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/) activation (implemented in the paper).